# "Authentication servers down for maintenance" error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can't connect to a local server, with the error "Authentication servers are down for maintenance." I have checked other posts here, but none of them solved my problem, because:

1. Mojang Service status shows all servers are up.
2. I can connect from another computer.

What might be a factor: since the last time this worked the local server has a new IP address.

The computer getting the error is a Linux client.

The version is 1.13.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this error still appear if you restart your client?

Comment: Yeah. One more detail: another linux client pc connects just fine. 

I will reinstall java and the minecraft package and try again.

Comment: Hmm... (I'm legitimately out of suggestions, that's very odd)

Answer (score 2):

Answer originally posted in comments:

---

SOLVED: Bad computer: `$ java -showversion java version "1.8.0_121` Good computer: `$ java -showversion openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17` Fix: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`

Answer (score -1):

Normally when receiving an error to do with authentication, it is to do with malicious software altering your host files (eg illegal alt generators). To fix host files (on MacOS and Linux):

> **1)** Press cmd+space and type "Terminal" into spotlight, then press enter on the terminal app
> **2)** type in `sudo nano /etc/hosts` It will ask for your password, this is so that it can edit a system file. It will not show the password as you are typing it for security reasons, but it is receiving the input
> **3)** Remove every line mentioning 'Mojang' using the arrow keys to navigate ( Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2phKo.jpg )
> **4** Press Ctrl+O, then enter
> You should now be able to play Minecraft again, please never use any illegal tools or accounts again.

Comment: For anyone here with Windows, the fix is located [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCfixes/comments/knwmpg/authentication_error/)